# What does a red icon next to a field mean in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

While selecting fields for a `Candidate` Import in Taleo Connect Client, I noticed a small red icon next to a few of the fields. (IE: `EmailAddressValidated`, `Applications,Number`)

[image: Red icon next to field in Taleo Client Connect]

What does the red sign icon next to a field mean in Taleo Connect Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A red circle means this field's properties cannot be changed via Taleo Connect Client.

> There are several import field types:
>
> - Search or lookup fields are identified with a magnifying glass icon.
> - Key fields are identified with an orange key icon (visible after checking Use the value for search or lookup).
> - **Non updatable fields are identified with a red circle icon.**
> - User defined fields (UDFs) are identified with a person icon.
>
> <sub>*[Taleo Enterprise Connect Client User Guide v17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/18a/taleo/OTCCU/OTCCU.pdf) (Page 33)*</sub>

**Important Note:** While you can't update the field's properties, you ***can*** update the value of this field with a TCC import.